# How to track an email alert was send from a case

Tags: workflow, case, datetime, email-alert

I have a workflow that fires an email alert on certain condition to let customer know that the agents are on holidays. But unfortunately the workflow got fired before the specified datetime. Here is my workflow condition.

```
Source_Email__c ="testmail@gmail.com" && CreatedDate > DATETIMEVALUE("2018-03-29 16:00:00") && CreatedDate < DATETIMEVALUE("2018-04-02 16:30:00")
```

The email got fired on March 29th 3.10 PM itself. Does "DATETIMEVAULE" recognize the time according to the user time zone? Please let me know the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

"DATETIMEVAULE" is always calculated using GMT time zone irrespective of user's timezone.